# Javascript OnSubmit won't change the form's action

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

EDIT: Resolved. I didn't add quotations!

I am trying to update a form's action depending on the value inside a select box using JavaScript.

So far I have:

```
<form name="newStudent" method="POST" onsubmit=newStudent.action = document.newStudent.proceed.value>
```

and further down in my code:

```
<select name="proceed">
<option value="newSchedule.php">add student's schedule</option>
<option value="newStudent.php">add another student</option>
<option value="staff.php">staff page</option>;
```

Nothing happens when the submit button is pressed. What am I doing wrong?
The current page is newStudent.php so the form **should** redirect to newSchedule.php since it is selected.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute value contains spaces, so you need quotation marks around it:

```
<form name="newStudent" method="POST" onsubmit="newStudent.action = document.newStudent.proceed.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form name="newStudent" method="POST" onsubmit="this.action = document.newStudent.proceed.value">
```